# How do I building dt.hour in 2 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I did multi-day observation, one customer can be observed in more few days, Here's my data

```
customer_id   value    timestamp
1             1000     2018-05-28 03:40:00.000
1             1450     2018-05-28 04:40:01.000
1             1040     2018-05-28 05:40:00.000
1             1500     2018-05-29 03:40:00.000
1             1090     2018-05-29 04:40:00.000
3             1060     2018-05-18 03:40:00.000
3             1040     2018-05-18 05:40:00.000
3             1520     2018-05-19 03:40:00.000
3             1490     2018-05-19 04:40:00.000
```

What I did is `df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour`,  but it only show the hour, but why I need is, because experiment cycle is can be 2-6 days

```
customer_id   value    timestamp                hour
1             1000     2018-05-28 03:40:00.000  Day1 - 3
1             1450     2018-05-28 04:40:01.000  Day1 - 4
1             1040     2018-05-28 05:40:00.000  Day1 - 5
1             1500     2018-05-29 03:40:00.000  Day1 - 3
1             1090     2018-05-29 04:40:00.000  Day2 - 4
3             1060     2018-05-18 03:40:00.000  Day1 - 3
3             1040     2018-05-18 05:40:00.000  Day1 - 5
3             1520     2018-05-19 03:40:00.000  Day2 - 3
3             1490     2018-05-19 04:40:00.000  Day2 - 4
```

Comment: is that new `hour` column what you want the output to be?

Comment: Yes, that is my expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) for count [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)s and last join all together:

```
a = df.groupby('customer_id')['timestamp'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x.dt.date)[0]) + 1

df['hour'] = 'Day' + a.astype(str) + ' - ' + df['timestamp'].dt.hour.astype(str)
print (df)
   customer_id  value           timestamp      hour
0            1   1000 2018-05-28 03:40:00  Day1 - 3
1            1   1450 2018-05-28 04:40:01  Day1 - 4
2            1   1040 2018-05-28 05:40:00  Day1 - 5
3            1   1500 2018-05-29 03:40:00  Day2 - 3
4            1   1090 2018-05-29 04:40:00  Day2 - 4
5            3   1060 2018-05-18 03:40:00  Day1 - 3
6            3   1040 2018-05-18 05:40:00  Day1 - 5
7            3   1520 2018-05-19 03:40:00  Day2 - 3
8            3   1490 2018-05-19 04:40:00  Day2 - 4
```

Alternative solution if consecutive dates per groups:

```
dates = df['timestamp'].dt.date
a = dates.sub(dates.groupby(df['customer_id']).transform('min')).dt.days + 1
```