# How to make day-hour count on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I did multi-day observation, one customer can be observed in more few days, Here's my data,

```
customer_id   value    timestamp
1             1000     2018-05-28 03:40:00.000
1             1450     2018-05-28 04:40:01.000
1             1040     2018-05-28 05:40:00.000
1             1500     2018-05-29 02:40:00.000
1             1090     2018-05-29 04:40:00.000
3             1060     2018-05-18 03:40:00.000
3             1040     2018-05-18 05:40:00.000
3             1520     2018-05-19 03:40:00.000
3             1490     2018-05-19 04:40:00.000
```

Based on previous question [How do I building dt.hour in 2 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036672/how-do-i-building-dt-hour-in-2-days) the first customer appear is `2018-05-28 03:40:00.000` and labelled as `Day1 - 3`, but for another purpose is should be `Day1 - 0`, so the output would be

```
customer_id   value    timestamp                hour
1             1000     2018-05-28 03:40:00.000  Day1 - 0
1             1450     2018-05-28 04:40:01.000  Day1 - 1
1             1040     2018-05-28 05:40:00.000  Day1 - 2
1             1500     2018-05-29 02:40:00.000  Day1 - 23
1             1090     2018-05-29 04:40:00.000  Day2 - 1
3             1060     2018-05-18 03:40:00.000  Day1 - 0
3             1040     2018-05-18 05:40:00.000  Day1 - 2
3             1520     2018-05-19 03:40:00.000  Day2 - 0
3             1490     2018-05-19 04:40:00.000  Day2 - 1
```

Comment: Output is correct? There is `23` and last `2` ?

Comment: Edited in expected output dataframe  `1             1500     2018-05-29 02:40:00.000  Day1 - 23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need add all mising hours for correct [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
#floor to hours
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('h')
#add missing hours per group
df = df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('customer_id').apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('h'))
#cumulative count per group
df['hour'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() 
df= df.dropna(subset=['customer_id']).drop('customer_id', 1).reset_index()

df['hour'] = ('Day' + (df['hour'] // 24).add(1).astype(str) +
              ' - ' + (df['hour'] % 24).astype(str))
print (df) 
   customer_id           timestamp   value       hour
0            1 2018-05-28 03:00:00  1000.0   Day1 - 0
1            1 2018-05-28 04:00:00  1450.0   Day1 - 1
2            1 2018-05-28 05:00:00  1040.0   Day1 - 2
3            1 2018-05-29 02:00:00  1500.0  Day1 - 23
4            1 2018-05-29 04:00:00  1090.0   Day2 - 1
5            3 2018-05-18 03:00:00  1060.0   Day1 - 0
6            3 2018-05-18 05:00:00  1040.0   Day1 - 2
7            3 2018-05-19 03:00:00  1520.0   Day2 - 0
8            3 2018-05-19 04:00:00  1490.0   Day2 - 1
```

Comment: I'm already revise the question, but why `2018-05-29 02:40:00` give  `Day2 - 0 ` instead of `Day1 - 23'

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Unfortunately :(

Comment: Do you miss something

I'm already revise the question, but why 2018-05-29 02:40:00 give Day2 - 23 instead of `Day1 - 23'

Comment: Why you make `df1` instead still using `df`?

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Yes, reason was I first think need count `Days` from original df. But now it shoud be df.

Comment: Still running, the actual data is big

Comment: The last code works well, need some descriptive statistics check